# Converting 4D to 2D array gives me: ValueError: shapes (88,4) and (88,2) not aligned: 4 (dim 1) != 88 (dim 0)

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning

Im trying to use PCA (Principal Component Analysis) to transform a 4D array into a 2D array.

However I have this error:

> valueError: Shapes (88,4) and (88,2) not aligned: 4 (dim 1) != 88 (dim 0).
>
> ---
>
> ```
> ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
>  in 
>      21 PCevals, PCevecs = __PCA(trainingFeatures)
>      22 
> ---> 23 trainingFeatures2D = __transformData(trainingFeatures, PCevecs)
>      24 validationFeatures2D = __transformData(validationFeatures, PCevecs)
>      25 testingFeatures2D = __transformData(testingFeatures, PCevecs)
>
> in __transformData(features, PCevecs)
>      16 
>      17 def __transformData(features, PCevecs):
> ---> 18     return np.dot(features,  PCevecs[:, 0:2])
>      19 
>      20
> ```
>
> <**array_function** internals> in dot(*args, **kwargs)
>
> ValueError: shapes (88,4) and (88,2) not aligned: 4 (dim 1) != 88 (dim 0)

---

```
def __PCA(data):
    # Extract data dimensions
    d, N = data.shape

    # First, center the data
    center = np.mean(data, 1)
    centers = np.matlib.repmat(center, N, 1)
    data_cent = data - np.transpose(centers)

    # Compute covariance and its eigenvalues from centered data
    Sigma = np.cov(data_cent)
    evals, evecs = np.linalg.eigh(Sigma)

    # Return eigenvalues and eigenvectors
    return np.flip(evals,0), np.flip(evecs, 1)

def __transformData(features, PCevecs):
    return np.dot(features,  PCevecs[:, 0:2])

PCevals, PCevecs = __PCA(trainingFeatures)

trainingFeatures2D = __transformData(trainingFeatures, PCevecs)
validationFeatures2D = __transformData(validationFeatures, PCevecs)
testingFeatures2D = __transformData(testingFeatures, PCevecs)
print('shape training = ', trainingFeatures2D.shape)
print('shape validation = ', validationFeatures2D.shape)
print('shape testing = ', testingFeatures2D.shape)
```

---

```
print('shape training = ', trainingFeatures.shape)
print('shape validation = ', validationFeatures.shape)
print('shape testing = ', testingFeatures.shape)
```

yields the following output:

```
shape training =  (88, 4)
shape validation =  (29, 4)
shape testing =  (31, 4)
```

Comment: Transpose `features` to produce a (4,2) result

Comment: Review the dimension rules for `np.dot`.